# While loop in Math::getGradeTotal(string continuegrade) gives error

Tags: c++

So essentially what I'm trying to do here is have the user put in their grade information and then in a specific function ask if them if they would like to continue putting in grades. When I try this however I get an error with the while loop so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I have provided all the code so that you guys can get a better understanding of what I'm trying to do. I get the error at "Math::getGradeTotal(string continuegrade)" and it says in the compiler

These are the errors they're spitting out in the compiler

Line 23: error: prototype for 'int Math::getGradeTotal()(std::_cxxll::string)' does not math any in class
Line 23: error: candidate is std::_cxxll::string Math::getGradeTotal()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Math.h"
using namespace std;

string student_name;
double test_grade;


int main()
{

    string continuegrade;
    double gradeinput;
    char courseinput;

    cout << "Please enter students name: " << endl;
    cin >> student_name;

    cout << "Please select what course you would like to enter grades (1- 
     Math, 2-Science): "<< endl;
    cin >> courseinput;

   cout << "Please insert grade:" << endl;
   cin >> gradeinput;


    Math Student1(gradeinput, continuegrade);

    if (courseinput == '1') 
    {
        cout << "Grade put in:" << Student1.getGrade() << endl;
        Student1.getGradeTotal();
    }
    if (courseinput == '2')
   {
        cout << "**You have selected Science**" << endl;
    } 



    return 0;
}
```

### Header File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef MATH_H
#define MATH_H

class Math
{
    public:
        //default constructor
        Math();

        //overload constructor
        Math(double , string);

        //destructor
        ~Math();

        //accessor functions
        double getGrade();
            //getGrade - gets the input of the grade
        string getGradeTotal();
            //getGradeTotal - takes the input and adds onto itself

    private:
        //Member variables
        double new_gradeinput;
        string new_continuegrade;
};

#endif // MATH_H
```

### .CPP Source File

```
#include "Math.h"

Math::Math()
{
    new_gradeinput = 0.0;
    //ctor
};

Math::Math(double gradeinput, string continuegrade)
{
    new_gradeinput = gradeinput;
    //new_continuegrade = continuegrade;
};

Math::~Math()
{
};

double Math::getGrade()
{
    return new_gradeinput;
}

Math::getGradeTotal(string continuegrade)
{
    new_continuegrade = continuegrade;
    while ((new_continuegrade == 'Y') || (new_continuegrade == 'y'))
    {
        cout << "Would you like to continue" << endl;
        cin >> new_continuegrade;
    }

    /*cout << "Grade total: " << new_gradeinput << endl;
    return new_gradeinput;*/


}
```

I know this is kind of long but any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your declaration of `getGradeTotal` doesn't match the definition. One is `string getGradeTotal();`, the other is `getGradeTotal(string continuegrade)`.

Comment: There are differences between function definitions and implementations in the `Math` header and CPP files.  In particular `getGradeTotal()` - parameter and return type (see also call in main.cpp).  Function body does not return anything, and compares `std::string` with `char` (I would have thought this OK, but GCC says "no").

Comment: "this is kind of long" So make it smaller. [mcve] PS How is the error message not clearly telling you the problem?